# Twilio throwing error as unreachable destination handset

Tags: google-cloud-platform, twilio, twilio-api

We are using twilio for sending messages but as Twilio(Text Messaging) integration was shutting down we deployed the integration using cloud run by following steps from https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dialogflow-integrations/tree/master/twilio#readme
After deployment messages were sending successfully but now suddenly we are getting errors in twilio like
[image]

Some messages are sending successfully and for some messages we are getting error.can anybody help me in this.thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

According to [Twillio docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/30003) there might be some possible causes for `Unreachable destination handset`

```
1.The destination handset you are trying to reach is switched off or otherwise unavailable.
2.The device you are trying to reach does not have sufficient signal
3.The device cannot receive SMS (for example, the phone number belongs to a landline)
4.There is an issue with the mobile carrier
```

[Possible Solutions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/30003#possible-solutions)

```
The first step to troubleshooting this issue is to attempt to replicate the problems. 
Attempt to send another test message to this user via a REST API request, or through the API Explorer in the Twilio Console.
```